# Question on the space of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Define the total variation norm in the space of probability measures $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by 
$$
\Vert \mu - \nu \Vert = \sup_D\lbrace | \mu(D) - \nu(D)| \rbrace.
$$
I am to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, I find a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $\Vert \mu - \nu \Vert < \delta$, there are measures $\tau, \mu', \nu'$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mu &= (1-\varepsilon)\tau + \varepsilon \mu', \\
\nu &= (1- \varepsilon)\tau + \varepsilon \nu'.
\end{align*}
It would suffice to show that there is a $\tau$ such that $\mu, \nu \geq (1-\varepsilon)\tau$. I have tried doing this by choosing $\tau$ as the center of a ball of diameter $\delta$ containing $\mu$ and $\nu$ so that $(1-\varepsilon)\tau$ would then drop too far from the ball, causing the inequality, but this obviously isn't working since $\tau$ can be very close to $0$ and the difference between $(1 - \varepsilon)\tau$ and $\tau$ would be insignificant compared to $\delta$.

Playing with minimums of $\mu(D), \nu(D)$ isn't working either since I can't build a $\sigma$-additive measure by combining them.

I know that the space we are in is a complete metric space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda = \mu +\nu$. Let $f$ and $g$ be the densities of $\mu $ and $\nu $ w.r.t. $\lambda$ Let $\tau (A)=\int_A \min \{f,g\} d\lambda$ Then $\tau \leq \mu$ and $\tau \leq \nu$. Of course $\tau $ is not a probability measure. Can you now use that fact that $||\mu -\nu || <\delta$ to see that normalized form of $\tau $ works? [Roughly speaking $f$ and $g$ are almost the same and $\tau $ is almost a  probability measure].

Comment: Assuming $\Vert \mu - \nu \Vert < \delta$, $\mu(\lbrace \nu 's\ support \rbrace^c) < \delta$ and $\nu(\lbrace \mu 's\ support \rbrace^c) < \delta$. Hence $\mu$ and $\nu$ both give mass of $\geq 1 - \delta$ to the intersection of their supports which then has positive $\tau$ mass. Therefore $\tau$ can be normalized? I'll check if I got something wrong.